# Javascript templates

Tags: javascript, templates, genshi

Does anyone know if is there any way to create javascrit templates in Genshi? I mean, I need a .js file where I can use directives like `<py:for>` and so.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write it directly in html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<py:if test="func1">
/*&lt;![CDATA[*/
      function func1() {
      }
/*]]&gt;*/
</py:if>
</script>
```

note: code inside CDATA will be right escaped, so you can use '>','<' as usual.