# How to render a javascript template inside Genshi?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, mustache, genshi

I'd like to render a mustache/handlebars template inside a genshi template. Genshi seems to raise a TemplateSyntaxError because of the mustache tags.

I've tried to put CDATA tags, as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201343/javascript-templates), either inside and outside `<script>`:

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-mustache-template">
    <![CDATA[
    ... my template here ...
    ]]>
</script>
```

Since I do `$('#some-template').html()`, Handlebars just renders the CDATA tag together with the rest of the html, which messes the result.

```
<![CDATA[
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-mustache-template">
    ... my template here ...
</script>
]]>
```

This way, the browser comments the first `<script>` tag.

Also, commenting the CDATA with `<!-- -->` raises the error, and inside the script with `/* */` just causes Handlebars to print it as is.

Is there any way to tell Genshi not to parse a chunck of the template?

Thanks!

Comment: Ended up wrapping it like my first example and then using `Handlebars.compile($(selector).html().replace(/<![CDATA[|]]>/, ''))` which is not ideal... Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but I ran into a similar problem.

I have a chunk of markup that is being run through an XML parser, which adds a handlebars template to the DOM that will later be compiled by script.

In order to get the handlebars template past the XML parser, I needed to wrap with a CDATA block, but that was causing similar issues to yours.  If I put the CDATA inside the script tags, the first bit of template markup was being swallowed in a comment.  If I put them outside, the entire template was being commented and was unreachable by the script call to compile it.

I was able to get around it by inserting an HTML comment as an unnecessary shield to get swallowed, like so:

```
<div id="contentChunk">
    <div id="blah" class="foo">
        Some vanilla HTML being added.
    </div>
    <script id="hbTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <![CDATA[
        <!-- blocker comment: first html node of handlebars script gets swallowed. -->
        {{#each data.items}}
        <div id="item{{id}}">{{{name}}}</div>
        {{/each}}
        <!-- ]]> -->
    </script>
</div>
```

I also wrapped the trailing CDATA close tag in comments, otherwise I was getting a literal ]]> to render.

Comment: Thanks for your input. If I remember correctly, that happened to me too, and that's why I ended up removing the CDATA tag before compiling the template (check my comment in the question).

Answer (score 1):

You could put your CDATA delimiters within mustache comments:

```html
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-mustache-template">
    {{! <![CDATA[ }}
    ... my template here ...
    {{! ]]> }}
</script>
```

(This is essentially the same trick as using `// <![CDATA[` and `// ]]>` for JavaScript scripts.)

Comment: Bruno, good suggestion, but unfortunately (in my case) the trailing }}'s were breaking XML validation of the <script> tag.  May work for Genshi... ?

Comment: Handlebars, but remotely fetching the templates via jQuery.  And, unfortunately, I did not have control over the dataType for the jQuery .ajax call, which was set to 'xml' for me.  The XML validation inside jQuery was what was failing - everything client side was totally cool with the markup, either way.